# Cordova cross-domain file:// iframe contentwindow communication

Tags: javascript, cordova, iframe, cross-domain

I found that i can do cross-domain communication from a page on `file://` and an iframe hosted on a remote host with the contentWindow property of the iframe.

For example on the device I have an html page at the url file://.../index.html that loads cordova and contains an iframe:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<iframe id="appframe"></iframe>
```

On this page I can execute a javascript that loads the iframe and save a reference of an object in the iframed page like this:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("appframe");
iframe.onload = function(){
    iframe.contentWindow.cordova = window.cordova;
}
iframe.src = "http://www.example.com/appframe.html";
```

Now on the page inside the iframe, http://www.example.com/appframe.html, i can execute a cordova call, for example:

```
cordova.exec(null, null, "StatusBar", "hide", []);
```

and this unexpectedly works, calling the native layer of the StatusBar cordova plugin and hiding the statusbar.

My question is:

**Is this safe to use or is an hack that won't work in future version of the browsers?**

I tested it on iOS 9 and Android 5 devices.

Comment: does this work if the appframe is served from file:/// ?

Comment: Interesting. IMO it's very unsafe to do it, if you don't control the remote website - when they learn that you embed their code in your app, they can adjust their code and `cordova.exec` anything that your app supports via a plugin, and maybe with conjuction with some other bug, get really big privilege escalation. Having said that, you need to explicitly inject the reference to `cordova` into the iframe for this to work, so it's not a security hole unless you let it be.

Comment: @mircoc Like you I am also trying to load html pages(size of pages goes from 5Mb to 100Mb) in iframe but many times app crashes with error 'Out of memory'. Did you face this type of problem? if yes, can you guide me how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I Believe that the safer way to communicate between frames is `postMessage` as described in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), do it in a different way could cause inconsistency between devices (Remember how fragmented is android and how painful could be the backward compatibility with 4.3 and below)

So, you could get the iFrame element and then post a msg like

`otherWindow.postMessage(InfoToSend, "*");`

In the same way you could listen to that event inside the frame:

`window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);`

This will no cause cross-frame issues and it will be the safer way to pass information, the bad news is that you will not be able to pass the `window.cordova` instance, so you will need to establish a conversation between the `iFrame` and the `window.top` frame.

Comment: [This bug in Cordova's JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4897) votes to implement support for `postMessage`, too, and also presents a way to secure the communication via the iframe via a _secret shared key_.

Answer (score 0):

I think that probably you have in your config.xml the following tag.

```
<access origin="*" />
```

as described here
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/whitelist/ you could restrict the cross domain policy to specified domains used as value of the property "origin" instead of using a wildcard.

So if you are using the wildcard value, this should be the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

With this PR you can fall back to using files instead of https://localhost with this preference:

```
<preference name="AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled" value="true" />
```